# How to properly express my happiness - しあわせになりました。

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verbs

So pardon for this being quite a specific question, but I'm trying to communicate this idea in a letter:

> Looks like you had fun, so I'm glad.

Actually I'm finding it difficult to get my Japanese right in expressing this.　This is what I have so far:

> Emilyさん は たのしかったのようなですねから、わたししあわせになりました。

I'm unsure of whether it would be なりました or なる. In fact, I'm unsure of the sentence in general - the ような part is important because I don't want to say 'you definitely had fun!', but I'm a little confused about how to structure it. Does it sound unnatural?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

幸せ｛しあわせ｝ is used for long-lasting happiness or a state of happiness that continues.  A better word could be 嬉｛うれ｝しい .

So your sentence could be:

> Emilyさんは楽しかったようですから、私も嬉しいです！

Answer (score 2):

You could say 楽｛たの｝しい or 嬉｛うれ｝しい (i.e., 私は楽しい/嬉しい). In addition, you could also say that something which makes you happy is 楽しい (e.g., 楽しい映画 "fun movie").

幸｛しあわ｝せ is happiness that's more sublime and persistent. Also, with 幸せ, you don't need to use になります. You could just say, like, 私は幸せでした.